# OSX: programmatically get list of applications for a file

Tags: python, objective-c, macos, command-line

In the finder, a user can right click / "open with" and see a list of applications that can be used to open the file.

How can I get this list of applications programmatically?

ObjC or Python preferred, but also curious if there's a command line utility that exposes this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSArray *applicationURLs = CFBridgingRelease(LSCopyApplicationURLsForURL((__bridge CFURLRef)fileURL, kLSRolesAll));
NSLog(@"applicationURLs %@", applicationURLs);
```

// Output

```
applicationURLs (
    "file:///Applications/calibre.app/",
    "file:///Applications/Archiver.app/",
    "file:///Applications/Pacifist.app/",
    "file:///System/Library/CoreServices/Archive%20Utility.app/"
)
```

For default app:

```
   CFURLRef defaultApplicationForURL = NULL;
   LSGetApplicationForURL((__bridge CFURLRef)fileURL, kLSRolesAll, NULL, &defaultApplicationForURL);
   NSLog(@"deafultApplicationForURL %@", defaultApplicationForURL);
```

// Output

```
deafultApplicationForURL file:///System/Library/CoreServices/Archive%20Utility.app/
```